# Do not run scheduled tasks before application is ready

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to postpone scheduled task (or not execute it at all) until application is ready (i.e. until after ApplicationReadyEvent)?

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */4 * * *")
    fun foo() {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring scheduler which is run after application is started and after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377627/spring-scheduler-which-is-run-after-application-is-started-and-after-midnight)

Comment: Not really. These are different problems. I don't want my scheduled jobs to run during application startup (i.e. before it reaches ready state).

Comment: what about implementing `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` in your component where you have your scheduled task? So having field `boolean initialized = false` which will be changed to true based on `ApplicationReadyEvent` and only after that your job can be executed. So `fun foo() { if (!initialized) return; ... }`