# Spring Scheduled cron job for every 9 hrs after starting the server(IF server starts at 2:15 PM and next task should happen at 11:15Pm)

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

I need to run a job in spring boot for every 9 hours. I have used @Scheduled(cron = "0 */9 * * *") for running the job .But when the run the application I am getting error as "Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'data': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields"

Please anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html) to find the correct cron expression.

According this site try this cron expression:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * ? * *")
```

Also try this as alternative:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */1 * * *")
```

Comment: When I use the  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */1 * * *")  the task again after 10 mins.

Comment: Are you sure that everything in your code is correct? It is sound strange because the first field (`0`) means start at 00 seconds, second filed - start 00 minutes and third field (`*/1`)- repeat every hours. Nothing common with 10 mins.

Comment: I want the task to happen one hour after the server starts. When I used @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 * * *") : Server starts as 2.06 PM and the next schedued job starts at 3.00 PM but it should happen at 3:06PM. What I should do to achieve it?

Comment: It's more complex. You need to configure scheduler programmatically. I recommend to see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719770/3454339 , it is the way to execute scheduler when application is ready. And you need to configure cron expression manually according your start time. Read this article it may be helpful https://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler#scheduling-with-crontrigger

Comment: Is there any way the the job should run every 1 hour after application start. Suppose application started at 4:15, the next should run at 5:15 next at 6:15..so and so

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses an extended cron syntax:

From the [@Scheduled docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--)

> A cron-like expression, extending the usual UN*X definition to include triggers on the second, minute, hour, day of month, month, and day of week.
> For example, "0 * * * * MON-FRI" means once per minute on weekdays (at the top of the minute - the 0th second).
>
> The fields read from left to right are interpreted as follows.
>
> - second
> - minute
> - hour
> - day of month
> - month
> - day of week
>
> The special value "-" indicates a disabled cron trigger, primarily meant for >externally specified values resolved by a ${...} placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to rely on the application start time then you shouldn' use cron but use `fixedDelay` instead

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 9 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 9 hours in milliseconds
```